# Arraylist that stores radio button states won't update with set method in android studio

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an arraylist with a custom object that stores the radio button states for a recyclerview. The radiobutton states are saved in the recyclerview and everytime a view is recycled it carries the state with it. So I decided to save the state of the button clicked in an arraylist of object "RadioButtonStates" which stores the checked id, the adapter position clicked and whether the state was clicked or not. I filled the arraylist with dummy values of "false, 0, 0" and in an onclick method i change the value of the radiobuttonstate with the set method. But the set method doesn't work. I feel as if the problem is that i am referring to an instance of the arraylist and not the arraylist. But when I declare the method as static, it doesn't make a difference.

```
public class WordQuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context mContext;
Random random = new Random();
ArrayList<WordMaps> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
//arraylist which stores buttonstates
private  static ArrayList<RadioButtonStates> buttonStates = new ArrayList<>();
//universalViewHolder object allows to get an instance of the holder from onBindViewholder in order to use available methods.
ViewHolder universalViewHolder;

private RadioGroup radioGroup;




public WordQuestionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<WordMaps> wordMapsArrayList) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.wordList = wordMapsArrayList;


}



public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public CardView cardView;

    public RadioButton meaning_1, meaning_2, meaning_3, meaning_4;
    public RadioGroup radioGroup;

    public ViewHolder(CardView view) {
        super(view);
        cardView = view;

        meaning_1 = (RadioButton) cardView.findViewById(R.id.meaning_1);
        meaning_2 = (RadioButton) cardView.findViewById(R.id.meaning_2);
        meaning_3 = (RadioButton) cardView.findViewById(R.id.meaning_3);
        meaning_4 = (RadioButton) cardView.findViewById(R.id.meaning_4);
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) cardView.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);


    }


}

@Override
public WordQuestionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CardView cV = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) cV.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);


//for loop which stores the dummy values in order to deal with NPE's
    for(int i = 0; i<5999;i++){
        buttonStates.add(i, (new RadioButtonStates(false, 0, 0)));

    }
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(cV);


    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position)

{

    Log.i("* Cases", "View binded");

    universalViewHolder = holder;
    final CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
    int true_random_position = random.nextInt(wordList.size());
    TextView wordText = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.word);


    switch (random.nextInt(3)) {

        case 0:

            Log.i("* Cases", "Case 0 called");
            wordText.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getWord());
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_1);
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_2);
             //Checks if radioButton is clicked. If boolean of getter and setter returns false,
            //then value is not clicked.
            if (!buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getSetChecked()) {
                Log.i("* RadioGroup", "radioGroup cleared");
                holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
            } else {
                Log.i("* RadioGroup", "radioGroup checked "+buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
                holder.radioGroup.check(buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
            }


            break;

        case 1:
            Log.i("* Cases", "Case 1 called");
            wordText.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getWord());
            Log.i("position", "" + position);
            Log.i("wordText", "" + wordList.get(true_random_position).getWord());
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_2);
            //Checks if radioButton is clicked. If boolean of getter and setter returns false,
            //then value is not clicked.
            if (!buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getSetChecked()) {
                Log.i("RadioGroup", "radioGroup cleared");
                holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
            } else {
                Log.i("RadioGroup", "radioGroup checked"+buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
                holder.radioGroup.check(buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            Log.i("* Cases", "Case 2 called");
            wordText.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getWord());
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_3);
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_2);
            //Checks if radioButton is clicked. If boolean of getter and setter returns false,
            //then value is not clicked.
            if (!buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getSetChecked()) {
                holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
                Log.i("* RadioGroup", "radioGroup checked" + buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
            } else {
                holder.radioGroup.check(buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
                Log.i("* RadioGroup", "radioGroup checked" + buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
            }


            break;
        case 3:
            Log.i("* Cases", "Case 3 called");
            wordText.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getWord());
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_4);
            holder.meaning_1.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_2.setText(wordList.get(true_random_position).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_3.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            holder.meaning_4.setText(wordList.get(random.nextInt(wordList.size())).getMeaning());
            onRadioButtonClicked(R.id.meaning_2);
            //Checks if radioButton is clicked. If boolean of getter and setter returns false,
            //then value is not clicked.

            if (!buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getSetChecked()) {
                holder.radioGroup.clearCheck();
            } else {
                //else value is clicked
                holder.radioGroup.check(buttonStates.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
            }


    }
    Log.i("* Adapter Position", ""+universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

//Radiobutton which checks if the object being clicked is the right one
public void onRadioButtonClicked(final int checkButtonSelect){

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

 universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition();





            if(checkedId!=-1) {
                Log.i("* checkedButtonId", "" + checkedId);
                if (checkedId == checkButtonSelect) {
      buttonStates.set(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), new RadioButtonStates(true, checkedId, universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));

                    //log statements which check if values were changed. Always returns false"
                    Log.i("* ButtonState id", "" + buttonStates.get(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
                    Log.i("* ButtonState position", "" +buttonStates.get(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAdapterPosition());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "CORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                   buttonStates.set(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), new RadioButtonStates(true, checkedId, universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
                    //log statements which check if values were changed. Always returns false"
                    Log.i("* ButtonState boolean", "" + buttonStates.get(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getSetChecked());
                    Log.i("* ButtonState id", "" + buttonStates.get(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getCheckedId());
                    Log.i("* ButtonState position", "" +buttonStates.get(universalViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getAdapterPosition());

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "INCORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }

        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return wordList.size();
}


}
```

UPDATE: the `set()` method does work, however it only works at the final position that is visible on screen. I.e. in this case, it would only set the option at position 2 when clicked, ignoring 0 and 1. I'll try passing the value of the holder to the method itself. E.g. `onRadioButtonClicked(final int checkButtonSelect, final ViewHolder holder`. Hopefully this syntax solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `universalViewHolder` only saved the last holder reference and didn't access the holders real time. So when I wanted to change the data in the `buttonstates` arraylist i had a huge problem because it would not change the value at the position clicked but at the final reference to the holder in `onBindViewHolder`. By getting a direct reference through changing the `onRadioButtonClicked` to accepting a direct reference of the `holder` when invoked by accepting two parameters, i had direct access to the adapter positions.